# Git does not show a new folder with files to add and commit

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a problem that for me does not make sense.
In my project I have a .gitignore working very well:

```
/some/folder
!/some/folder/some.properties
!/some/folder/some.xml
!/some/folder/somefolder/*
!/some/folder/anotherfolder/some.jar
```

I just need ignore a new folder, so I add the following:

```
/some/folder
!/some/folder/some.properties
!/some/folder/some.xml
!/some/folder/somefolder/*
!/some/folder/anotherfolder/some.jar

!/some/folder/my-new-folder-with-files/*
```

my-new-folder-with-files is not showed to add and commit files.

Can anybody help-me?

Comment: what does `git check-ignore -v` tells you about it?

Comment: Nothing is showed

Comment: Specifying the path you care for? That command and output are relevant in the question, can you add it in there?

Comment: Yes, I've executed both commands and result is the same.
git check-ignore -v
and
git check-ignore -v /some/folder

Comment: If it's not listed there then it is _not_ being ignored. Sure you have files in the directory? An empty dir is not handled by git.